# problem in design view

Tags: asp.net

I have designed a user control but its design view is not visible,can anybody help me out.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Note.ascx.cs" Inherits="MFActivityPlanning.usercontrols_Note" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="UserThumbNail" Src="~/usercontrols/UserThumbNail.ascx" %>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Trims the blank space from the start and end of string
    function Trim(objValue) {
        var lRegExp = /^\s*/;
        var rRegExp = /\s*$/;
        objValue = objValue.replace(lRegExp, ""); //Perform LTRim
        objValue = objValue.replace(rRegExp, ""); //perform RTrim
        return objValue;
    }
    //Check for special characters
    function ValidateString(inputText) {

        if (inputText.match(/[<>]/)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (inputText.match(/(&#)/)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .cal_Theme .ajax__calendar_container
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: solid 1px #cccccc;
    }
    .cal_Theme .ajax__calendar_title
    {
        border: none;
    }
</style>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlNotes" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentObjectID" runat="server" />
        <div align="center">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upProgNotes" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upPnlNotes" DynamicLayout="true"
                runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div align="center">
                        <div align="center" class="waitMessageStyle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <cc1:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender TargetControlID="upProgNotes" ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender1"
                runat="server" UseAnimation="true" HorizontalSide="Center" HorizontalOffset="1">
            </cc1:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
        </div>
        <table width="94%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="diaryLinkStatusStyle"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNote" runat="server" Width="99%" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Names="Arial"
                        MaxLength="4000" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="35%">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNote" runat="server" Text="Add Note" CssClass="btnStyle" OnClick="btnAddNote_Click">
                    </asp:Button>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCharacterLeft" runat="server" Text="4000 remains" CssClass="lblStyle"
                        Style="color: Gray;"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="right" width="65%" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFilterMsg" runat="server" CssClass="noteTimeStampStyle" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCancelFilter" runat="server" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel_filter.png"
                        OnClick="ibtnCancelFilter_Click" ToolTip="Clear Filter" />
                    <asp:Image ID="imgFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/filter.png" Visible="false"
                        ToolTip="Filter Notes" Style="cursor: pointer;" />
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="imgFilter_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgFilter"
                        PopupControlID="pnlFilter" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopupBackgroundStyle" DropShadow="True"
                        CancelControlID="ibtnCloseFilter">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server" Style="display: none" BackColor="Window"
                        BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" CssClass="pnlFilter">
                        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="Gray">
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right" style="width: 20px">
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPopupHeading" runat="server" Text="Filter Notes" CssClass="lblStyle"
                                                    Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right" style="width: 20px">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCloseFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/close.png" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNoteBy" runat="server" CssClass="lblStyle" Text="Note by: " />
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNoteBy" runat="server" Width="200" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                        CssClass="btnStyle">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNoteBy" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateBefore" runat="server" CssClass="lblStyle" Text="Added before: " />
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDtBefore" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" BorderWidth="0px"
                                        Width="80px" Text="Select a date" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCalbefore" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" />
                                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtDtBefore_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                        TargetControlID="txtDtBEfore" PopupButtonID="ibtnCalbefore" Format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                                        CssClass="cal_Theme">
                                    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDtBefore" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnClrDtBefore" runat="server" ToolTip="Clear date" ImageUrl="~/Images/clear_field.png" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDtAfter" runat="server" CssClass="lblStyle" Text="Added after: " />
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDtAfter" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" BorderWidth="0px"
                                        Width="80px" Text="Select a date" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCalAfter" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.gif" />
                                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtDtAfter_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                        TargetControlID="txtDtAfter" PopupButtonID="ibtnCalAfter" Format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                                        CssClass="cal_Theme">
                                    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDtAfter" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnClrDtAfter" runat="server" ToolTip="Clear date" ImageUrl="~/Images/clear_field.png" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSearchby" runat="server" CssClass="lblStyle" Text="Search by: " />
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="180" CssClass="txtStyle" />
                                    <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtFilter_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"
                                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtFilter" WatermarkText="Filter Expression"
                                        WatermarkCssClass="WaterMarkStyle">
                                    </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFilterSearch" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnApply" runat="server" Text="Apply" CssClass="btnStyle" OnClick="btnApply_Click" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Clear" CssClass="btnStyle" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPageSize" runat="server" CssClass="lblStyle" ForeColor="Gray" Text="Page Size:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" Width="50px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                        Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Gray" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnRefreshNoteList" ImageUrl="~/Images/refresh.png"
                        ToolTip="Refresh List" />
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:ListView ID="lvNoteList" runat="server" OnPreRender="lvNoteList_PreRender" OnItemDataBound="lvNoteList_ItemDataBound">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                <asp:Panel ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: top; "
                                class="<%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "noteListAlternetLine" %>">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="55px" align="center" valign="top" id="tdUserThumbnail" runat="server">
                                        <uc:UserThumbNail ID="ucThumbNail" runat="server" PhotoSize="Small" PhotoWeight="Low"
                                            ShowEdit="false" ShowName="False" ShowEmailID="true" IsUseExternalData="true" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" align="left">
                                        <div class="noteHeaderStyle">
                                            by
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="addMember" runat="server" Font-Underline="True">
                                            </asp:HyperLink>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Time" runat="server" CssClass="noteTimeStampStyle" Text='<%#FormatNoteTime(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("CREATED_ON")))%>'
                                                ToolTip='<%# "Added On: " + Eval("CREATED_ON")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="note" runat="server" class="noteTextStyle">
                                            <%#ParseExternalLinks(Convert.ToString(Eval("NOTE")).ToString().Replace("\n", "<br/>"))%></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                    <asp:DataPager ID="dpNoteList" runat="server" PageSize="15" PagedControlID="lvNoteList">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false"
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowLastPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false"
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Not with that giant wall of code. Can you reduce it to a minimal subset that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating you user control again, and this time add your control gradually and keep viewing the design view at regular intervals. Some point of time you will get to know which control is causing the issue.